# Rest API Pagination rules in Data Factory

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I cannot figure out pagination rule for REST Api in Data factory.
Query pulls by default 100 records. I can modify query with parameters `?skip=0&take=5000` and get more records. I cannot see next url in the output. And don't want to hardcode *take* parameter to 1000000. How can I paginate this call?
Thanks.
[image: data source]

[image: copy task]

[image: result]

Comment: Are you sure there isn’t something else in the API result like total number of pages.  Post an anonymised sample of the results?

Comment: can you add your sample rest api response?

Comment: Here is output sample
{
   "skip": 0,
   "take": 100,
   "rows":    [
            {
         "Number": "1000000",
         "Organisation_person": "XXX",
         "Name": "XXXX",
         "First_name": null,
         "Last_name": null,
         "Person_ISO_Alpha-3": null,
         "Entity_ISO_Alpha-3": "XXX",
         "Date_of_birth": null,
         "Date_CoC": "1991-02-01T00:00:00Z",
         "Blocked": false
      },

Answer (score 1):

According to this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support) you can use multiple pagination rules to paginate rest API if you don't have the next page URL but you can query the records.

You can follow below pagination rules:

1. You can use variables in Query parameter/ Absolute URL.
   Input `Skip={offset}` either in **Base URL** or **Relative URL** as shown in the following screenshots start is similar to skip and limit is similar to take:

[image]

And set  **Pagination rules**  as either option 1 or option 2：

- `"QueryParameters.{offset}" : "RANGE:0:10000:1000"`
- `"AbsoluteUrl.{offset}" : "RANGE:0:10000:1000"`

[image]

if your Api response contain value which refer to the total no of records you can directly mention it as `$node.node` in Endcondition.

2. If you don't want to hard code you can specify the **End condition** based on

- value of the specific node in response is empty
- value of the specific node in response does not exist
- value of the specific node in response exists
- value of the specific node in response is a user-defined const value etc.

Comment: I had to combine some of your other answers in other threats about this topic but finally it works, thanks.